# Does anyone know OR-Mapper adapted Json Type(MySQL or PostgreSQL)?

Tags: java, mysql, json, postgresql, scala

I'm developing data store application by Play framework 2.5(Scala).
And I wanna use MySQL and it's data type JSON.
Does anyone know OR-Mapper adapted to Json Type(MySQL or PostgreSQL)??

Researched list is below.

- Slick -> NG
- Anorm -> NG
- mapperdao -> NG
- morpheus -> NG
- mysql-async -> NG